# CMake says it has written build files, but no build files found

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build a very simple test project from sourice, using cmake. All my files are in the same directory: `alpha.h`, `alpha.cpp`, `beta.h`, `beta.cpp`, `main.cpp`. The contents of these files are as follows:

**alpha.h**

```
class Alpha
{
public:
    int x;
    Alpha();
}
```

**alpha.cpp**

```
#include "alpha.h"

Alpha::Alpha()
{
    x = 2;
}
```

**beta.h**

```
class Beta
{
public:
    int y;
    Beta();
}
```

**beta.cpp**

```
#include "beta.h"

Beta::Beta()
{
    y = 10;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "alpha.h"
#include "beta.h"

int main()
{
    Alpha a;
    Beta a;
    int x = a.x;
    int y = b.y;
    int z = x + y;
    return z;
}
```

I also have a `CMakeLists.txt` file in that same directory, whose content is:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Test)
add_executable(Test main.cpp alpha.cpp beta.cpp)
```

When I am in the directory with all these files, I enter `cmake .`, which gives the following output:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/karnivaurus/Data/Test-code/Test
```

However, I can see no build files in the directory `/home/karnivaurus/Data/Test-code/Test`. Why not?

Comment: 1. why do an in-source build? 2. did you type `make` to get it to compile?

Comment: When you say "no build files", does that mean that a file called Makefile does not exist in that directory?

Comment: So what is the content of `/home/karnivaurus/Data/Test-code/Test` after running CMake?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `cmake --trace .` It can provide you more information.

Comment: And it is recommended to use cmake from another location, for example - `mkdir build` `cd build` `cmake ..`